# PHP - How to get value of span with different class name

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get the values of two span with different class name and put it into array

this is the html

```
$html = '<div class="members">
            <span class="records">Name: </span>
            <span class="values">Marco</span>
        </div>
        <div class="members">
            <span class="records">Mobile: </span>
            <span class="values">+9431109890</span>
        </div>
        <div class="members">
            <span class="records">Age: </span>
            <span class="values">33</span>
        </div>
        <div class="members">
            <span class="records">Sex: </span>
            <span class="values">Male</span>
        </div>'
```

as for now i have this code

```
preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"records\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/", $html, $records);
preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"values\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/", $html, $values);
$valueresult = implode("\n", $records[1]); 
$recordresult = implode("\n", $values[1]);
```

i don't know how to put this in array 
or if you have much better coeds to put this in array.

result must be

```
  array(
    'Name'  => 'Marco',
    'Mobile' => '+000000000',
    'Age' => '33',
    'Sex' => 'Male,
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a regex master, but I've modified it to strip the `:` sign:

```
preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"records\"\>(.*?):(.*?)\<\/span\>/", $html, $records);
preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"values\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/", $html, $values);

$combined = array_combine($records[1], $values[1]);

print_r($combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"records\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/", $html, $records);
preg_match_all("/\<span class\=\"values\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/", $html, $values);

$recordresult = $values[1];
$valueresult = $records[1];

$result  = array_combine($valueresult, $recordresult);
var_dump($result);
```